# Understanding Migrations in Vapor-Fluent (Server side Swift)

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor, server-side-swift

I'm writing a web service in Swift using Vapor framework.

I have model named `Item`. Intially it has only name and id properties.

```
typealias VaporModel = Content & PostgreSQLModel & Parameter
final class Item: VaporModel {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String
}
```

After I configure a controller for the model and add the routes, when I hit the post Item request, I get the error as `Model.defaultDatabase is required to use as DatabaseConnectable`. I think the error is because I have not added `Item` to `Migrations` in `configure.swift` and I do the same after conforming `Item` to `PostgreSQLMigration`.

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Item.self, database: .psql)
services.register(migrations)
```

Now, I am able to hit the post request and create items in the database.

So I understand that `Migration` protocol creates the default schema for a model and adds a new table to the database with the model's properties as columns.

Now I want to add a property such as `price` to my Item class. Now when I hit the post request, I get the error as `column "price" of relation "Item" does not exist`. 
I assume the Migration protocol will be able to identify the schema changes and the column to my table (that's what I was used to in while using Realm for my iOS apps). But I am wrong and I read through the Migration docs and implement the `prepare` and `revert` methods in migration like below.

```
extension Item: PostgreSQLMigration {
    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: conn) { creator in
            creator.field(for: \.price)
        }
    }

    static func revert(on connection: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return Future.map(on: connection) { }
    }
}
```

I'm still struck with the same error `column "price" of relation "Item" does not exist`. What am I missing here? Is my migration code correct?

Also, I understand that if am not making any changes to the Model, I can comment out the migration config, because they need not run every time I run the service. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code you haven't added a new migration. You have implemented a manual initial migration, but the initial migration has run already as requested (`migrations.add(model: Item.self, database: .psql)`. To create a new migration you would need sth like:

```
struct ItemAddPriceMigration: Migration {
    typealias Database = PostgreSQLDatabase

    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {

        return Database.update(Item.self, on: conn) { builder in
            builder.field(for: \.price)
        }
    }

    static func revert(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return conn.future()
    }
}
```

And then you need to add it in `configure`:

`migrations.add(migration: ItemAddPriceMigration.self, database: .psql)`

Comment: I have already tried this approach and it did not work out. The code you have shared, did not build, and it build when I changed `self` to `Item.self`. Then when I run the service, I'm getting the error `Error raised at top level: ⚠️ PostgreSQL Error: relation "Item" already exists`

Comment: Sorry, it's `update`, not `create` of course. Answer updated.

Comment: thank you. that solved that error. how should I provide default values for the new column? because i am getting the error `column "price" contains null values`

Comment: Assuming `price` is an `Int` you would do `builder.field(for: \.price, type: .bigint, PostgreSQLColumnConstraint.default(.literal(1)))` for price of 1.

Comment: now I want to make price as double/float, i can do the migration as above and set default value but that will set all item prices in the database to the default value. How to migrate each item's price?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that, but I'd discourage you from using a floating point type to represent a price. It's a nightmare with rounding errors. Safe and simple is to use an integer that represents the number of 'cents'. So you would have 120 for $1.20 for instance.

Comment: That’s actually not my requirement. My requirement is that i am changing an enum of raw type int to string. I just asked with the price example i need not start a new thread.